# Intel(R) 82865G limited to MAX 96 MB Mem - Any way to override and increase?

Tags: video, memory-limit

I have an old HP desktop with an onboard Intel 82865G running Windows XP (SP3), and while it does 1920x1080, if something requires more than 96 MB of video memory, it crashes, or fails, or generates an error message saying it's trying to pass checks the Intel 82865G can't cash.

That's really irritating. Trying to watch a movie in full screen fails because the D3D renderer says we've hit the max and can't have more.

So, my question is as follows: is there a way to override this glass ceiling or am I stuck with a 96 MB cap? The system itself has 1.5 GB of RAM, of which (currently) 96 MB is shared with the video controller, but if possible I'd like to take that up higher, like 128 or even 256. Can it be done?

Comment: Seann,  edit you question to include the HP product number, so we can tell you if adding a upgrade video card is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have anything old enough to test this out, but there's a piece of software called [3d analyse](http://www.tommti-systems.de/go.html?http://www.tommti-systems.de/main-Dateien/files.html) that emulates a graphics card for games. On the short run, you might be able to run everything through an emulated graphics card with more ram on 3d analyser and possibly get things working.

On the longer run, Bon Gart is right, a pci video card is a much better option

Comment: It does have an AGP slot, 4x, I think. This particular model doesn't have it's family line printed on the case anywhere. It just says "HP Compaq" but it's a referb that was reclaimed from an office. If I can find a card laying around here, I'll pop it in. Also want to try 3D Analyse as that sounds interesting. The HP is just a placeholder system until my "proper" one is fixed (the one with my 1 GB DDR2 PCIE nVidia card :D ) so I'm not overly concerned about Intel's driver shenanigans.

Answer (score 1):

It cannot be done. [Your maximum memory allowed is 96MB](http://www.intel.com/support/graphics/intel865g/sb/CS-009174.htm?iid=graphics+865main).

> Memory size = Pre-allocated memory + Additional memory requested by the application via the Intel Extreme Graphics Driver.
>
> The sum total cannot exceed 96MB.

Comment: I disagree: the question was "can it be done." It appears not: 96MB is a hard limit imposed by the driver at the least and possibly even in hardware. bon gart's answer avoids the question entirely, not sure why that merits a +1 from you instead of a critique.

Comment: Question title says it all " Any way to override and increase?". I see Random edited your answer to improve it and actually answer the question asked.

Comment: Well... yes.  I did avoid the question, I just did not avoid the problem.  The question indeed, was whether or not the 96mb limit could be altered.  The problem was that he did not have enough video memory for what he wanted to do.  Answering the question leaves the problem unsolved.  I can see why you would want credit for answering the question, and not solving the problem.  I'll delete my answer.

Comment: I was responding to moab, not you bon gart. You are only mentioned in that moab +1 your answer, and critiqued mine. I don't want credit for anything, and the points don't matter. Moab is being obtuse if he thinks that random's edits actually materially change my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the info, guys. Since the limit is unbreachable, I'll give Journeyman's suggestion a try.